# cc calls standard cc even though I said "export CC=/path/to/other/compiler. How can that be?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gcc, cross-compiling

I’m on Ubuntu (Intel processor), trying to cross-compile for a server with a Realtek CPU. I installed the cross-compile development package. I can fire up the cross-compile gcc. Now, in order to have configure and make use the new compiler, I said:

```
export CC=/path/to/cross-compiler
```

but when I say `cc` in bash, it still calls the system vanilla gcc. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `alias cc='/path/to/cross-compiler'`?

Comment: Your `export` will be picked up by `make` not `bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cc` always calls system `cc`, this is expected behavior.

The `CC` variable is instead used by Makefiles, build scripts and configure scripts to suggest that they run a different executable. It is *not* used to allow anything to run the `cc` executable and in some way be redirected.

If you want to manually invoke the cross compiler, use `/path/to/cross-compiler -o foo foo.c`. If you have a script or command that hard codes `cc`, it's broken and must be fixed.